# Mouse Move event isnt working

Tags: mouseevent, mousemove, onmousemove

InitializeComponent();

```
        colorCB.SelectedIndex = 0;
        graficado = false;
        valuesLabel = new Label();
        Controls.Add(valuesLabel);

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(graficado)
        {
            if(listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            valuesL.Top = e.Y - 10;
            valuesL.Left = e.X - 15;
            valuesL.Width = 80;
            valuesL.Text = string.Format("({0:0.00},{1:0.00})",valoresX[listBox1.SelectedIndex,e.X],valoresY[listBox1.SelectedIndex,e.X]);
            valuesL.Refresh();
        }
```

I am working with graphics and I want the mouse to tell me where i am place in the coordinate plane. I created the event and i have no error marked, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are showing, graficado is set to false.
If iT isn't changed to true, the Form1_MouseMove method wil skipp the first if-block.